# using same .tfstate in 2 different projects

Tags: terraform

i have a question, lets assume i have the following structure:

Gitlab repo 1 with TFSTATE
gitlab repo 2 with brand new state for DR.

I know i'm able to consuming the outputs with remote state from repo 2 to repo 1, but there's a way to be able to modify the resources in repo 1 from repo 2? I mean, since the repo 2 dont have the resources and the "tfstate" is empty  i think its not possible, but, there's a workaround? maybe using the same tfstate in each project? in project 2 using the state from tf 1?
thanks.

Comment: Hey Emmanuel, since you're storing your `tfstate` file in a git repository, why do you need a different repository for DR? Creating a separate branch and protecting it should be enough unless there is a particular reason for the offered approach? Also, is it possible for you to store the `tfstate` file on remote object storage like AWS S3?

Comment: For security reasons you shouldn't store the .tfstate in a git repo as it may contain sensitive data such as passwords.
See: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/sensitive-data.html
Here is a sample of a .gitignore file for terraform :
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Terraform.gitignore

Comment: Maybe i didnt explain myself, we dont push the .tfstate in the repository, we just use the remote gitlab backend to store the .tfstate, the .tfstate is inside the "Operations - Terraform" , anyways we dont have any sensitive data in the .tfstate, any password or sensitive value is stored in parameter store / secret manager , so i think thats ok.
The main reason is to just update project A from B in case of disaster recovery, so i was searching for a workaround but it seems the only way to achieve that is to have the .tfstate in both repos, correct? anothe branch is not possible for now